# django - Display averages in template

Tags: python, django

I'm making a blog where users can leave comments/ratings on my posts. I want to display the average of all ratings for that specific post. How do I do that?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOISES = (

        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),

        )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    seo_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    seo_description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', default=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=STATUS_CHOISES, default='draft')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.slug])


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Comment(models.Model):
    difficulty_rating_choices = (

        (1, 'Very Easy'),
        (2, 'Easy'),
        (3, 'Moderate'),
        (4, 'Hard'),
        (5, 'Very Hard'),

    )

    workload_rating_choices = (

        (1, 'Very Light'),
        (2, 'Light'),
        (3, 'Moderate'),
        (4, 'Heavy'),
        (5, 'Very Heavy'),

    )

    book_rating_choices = (

        (1, '$'),
        (2, '$$'),
        (3, '$$$'),
        (4, '$$$$'),
        (5, '$$$$$'),

    )

    attendance_rating_choices = (

        (1, 'Not Required'),
        (2, 'Required'),


    )
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments")
    user = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    difficulty_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=difficulty_rating_choices)
    workload_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=workload_rating_choices)
    book_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=book_rating_choices)
    attendance_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=attendance_rating_choices)


    def approved(self):
        self.approved = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def add_comment(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:post_detail', slug=post.slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    template = "blog/post/add_comment.html"
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

template

```
<h1>Difficulty: <h1>
        <h1>Workload: <h1>
        <h1>Book Cost: <h1>
        <h1>Attendance: <h1>

        <hr>
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p>Written by {{ post.author }} on {{ post.published }}</p>
        <hr>
        {{ post.content|linebreaks }}
        <hr>
        <h2>Comments</h2>
        <p>Total number of comments: {{ post.comments.count }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'blog:add_comment' slug=post.slug %}">Leave a comment</a>
        {% for comment in post.comments.all %}


            <p>Title: {{ comment.title }}</p>
            <p>Review: {{ comment.body }}</p>
            <p>Date: {{ comment.created }}</p>
            <p>Posted by: {{ comment.user }}</p>
            <p>Difficulty: {{ comment.get_difficulty_rating_display }}</p>
            <p>Workload: {{ comment.get_workload_rating_display }}</p>
            <p>Book Cost: {{ comment.get_book_rating_display }}</p>
            <p>Attencance: {{ comment.get_attendance_rating_display }}</p>
            <hr>

        {% empty %}
            <p>There are no comments yet. Be the first one to comment!</p>

        {% endfor %}
```

I want the averages displayed for each of my 4 criteria (difficulty_rating, workload_rating, book_rating, attendance_rating) at the top of my template. How would I go about doing that? So far I haven't been able to figure it out..

Is this done at the template level? Do I have to edit my views.py? Or maybe even the model itself?

Comment: Calculate the average in the view, and pass it in to the template as a separate item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write helper method in your `Post` model:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    def avg_ratings(self):
        return self.comments.aggregate(
            Avg('difficulty_rating'),
            Avg('workload_rating'),
            Avg('book_rating'),
            Avg('attendance_rating'),
        )
```

Then in templates you could do:

```
{% with avg_ratings=post.avg_ratings %}
    {{ avg_ratings.difficulty_rating__avg }}
    {{ avg_ratings.workload_rating__avg }}
    {{ avg_ratings.book_rating__avg }}
    {{ avg_ratings.attendance_rating__avg }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: that worked! thank you! and what if I wanted to display their human readable counterpart instead? In my choices, I have for example in book_rating the human readable of '$$$' when the value is 3. Is there a way to do that? My guess is it would have to round it to the nearest whole number and go off of that?

Comment: No problem! Please create a separate question for this if you are stuck, but yes you need to round it to the nearest whole number and go from there. But what if avg came out to be 2.5 would you consider it to be 3 or 2? that's you need to decide.